# Edit specific listview item in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Is it possible to edit a specific listview item at runtime?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listViewServers.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if ( listViewServers.Items[i].COLUMNNAME == "My Column Name")
        {
           listViewServers.Items[i].COLUMNNAME.data = "New Cell Text";
        }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "edit a listview item" in WPF. There's DataBinding, which allows you to Bind the UI to actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. But should you do it? No. In WPF, you should use data binding to bind your controls to actual data, then, if you do it right, you can just change the data and the UI will update automatically. If you are not doing any fancy graphics or interactions, your code-behind (*.xaml.cs) should have no code apart from the autogenerated constructor  and you should not access controls from C# code.

I suggest reading up on data binding and the MVVM pattern, for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

That said, you can access the ListView items, but you have to know what you're putting into the Items collection or in ItemsSource (controls via XAML? controls via code? ViewModel classes with DataTemplates?). When you know this, you can just do:

```
foreach (YourClass obj in ListViewServers.Items.OfType<YourClass>())
{
  //do stuff with obj
}
```